# How to compile and execute this JAVA application in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, compiler-construction, javac, hdfs

[image: This is my folder structure of my java project]

There is a Hdfs.java inside *src/hdfs* and there is a utility jar file inside *lib*.

What are the options I give when I compile the Hdfs.java using the utility jar?
And how do I execute?

I went through the examples [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/icepick-javac.1.html) and I'm very confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to use the compiler inside of NetBeans, then go to your terminal application, set your current directory to `src` and invoke

```
javac -cp .:../lib/utility.jar Hdfs.java
```

To run, you would do this:

```
java -cp .:../lib/utility.jar Hdfs
```

If you want to compile and run within NetBeans, see Jigar Joshi's answer.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks. Just one question. What if I have two utilities in the lib folder? How do I include both of them ?

Comment: You'll need to specify both jars in the `-cp` argument: `javac -cp .:../lib/utility1.jar:../lib/utility2.jar Hdfs.java`  -- BTW if you are using Tomcat there are ways to package up a lot of jars into a war file, something you will want to look into eventually. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using net beans, right click on project and do **clean and build**

Comment: Ya I am using NetBeans. Actually I am trying to run the JAVA program using my jdk in the Ubuntu and not using the environment variables of NetBeans.

Comment: after doing clean and build click on your main java class right click on it and click on run

Comment: if you use NetBeans IDE, you can compile and run the application via IDE only

Comment: Just to be clear again, I created a project on my Ubuntu server from my NetBeans on Windows. The project compiles and runs fine on NB in Windows. Now since the project is in the webapps of TomCat on Ubuntu, I want to compile and execute this on my Ubuntu server.

Comment: If you have already installed tomcat right click project and click run